# Digits: What causes network issue 131?

Tags: google-fabric

In the last two weeks, we've seen our Digits conversion drop from 85-90% to 65-70%, without any major change on our end. Most of the drop has been on Step 2: Phone Number Submit (as shown in Fabric Answers).

One user sent us a screenshot that said there was a network issue (error 131) when they tried to submit their phone number. They could either Dismiss or Retry, but the Retry button kept taking them back to the same prompt. Normally I would suspect their internet connection, but when I put my phone in Airplane mode, it gives a different error (-1009). Answers also showed a jump in "UnclassifiedFailures" no that day, to 13%.

Anyone know what this error means? Is there anything we can do about it on our end, or was it potentially an outage?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. The 131 error should only happen when a user is trying to upload their contacts. From the [reference documentation:](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Digits/Constants/DGTErrorCode.html)

```
DGTErrorCodeUnableToUploadContactsInternalServer131
Contact upload failed due to internal server error 131
```

So the error is due to an issue on our end, but should only happen during the Friend Finder contact upload flow.